# case statement after join statement in SQL

Tags: sql, join, case

Data below, I need to select col4=301 only for col2=1. I got the data after joining few table using query like -

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
Select count(*),t.intWeightTypeId,t.locationid,t.airoccupancycode
from
(SELECT * 
FROM [AIRWork].[dbo].[t1551_c1_LOSS_StagingLocation_0A578891-5DF8-4F77-8AC4-0A9480148F1F] a
join [AIRGeography].[dbo].[TblSourceTargetMap_US] b on a.guidareaexternal=b.guidExternalSource
where locationtypecode='R' ) t 
group by t.intWeightTypeId,t.locationid,t.airoccupancycode
order by t.locationid


col1   col2       col3           col4
9   4   Loc_PE_14208    301
31  1   Loc_PE_14208    301
9   3   Loc_PE_14208    301
9   2   Loc_PE_14208    301
14  2   Loc_PE_14209    301
32  1   Loc_PE_14209    301
14  4   Loc_PE_14209    301
14  3   Loc_PE_14209    301
14  2   Loc_PE_14210    301
```

Comment: `where col4=301 and col2=1`? no idea what you're getting at...

Comment: What is the question? Why don't you just add a `WHERE` statement?

Answer (score 2):

You should do this with a `where` clause.  Assuming the columns match the column in the `SELECT`, you should use the column names.  You also don't need a subquery to do a `group by`:

```
  SELECT count(*), intWeightTypeId, locationid, airoccupancycode 
  FROM [AIRWork].[dbo].[t1551_c1_LOSS_StagingLocation_0A578891-5DF8-4F77-8AC4-0A9480148F1F] a join
       [AIRGeography].[dbo].[TblSourceTargetMap_US] b
        on a.guidareaexternal=b.guidExternalSource
  WHERE locationtypecode = 'R' AND
        airoccupancycode = 301 and intWeightTypeId = 1
  GROUP BY intWeightTypeId, locationid, airoccupancycode 
  ORDER BY locationid
```